# React + Axios - Data loaded able to console log but not showing up in DOM?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a problem with my simple React App. I'm able to connect to an API using Axios and can console log. However, I'm not able to output the data inside the DOM. it's empty why?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

    state = {
        fragrances: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:1337/fragrances')
        .then(res => {
        const fragrances = res.data;
        this.setState({ fragrances });
        })
    }

    render() {
    const { fragrances }  = this.state;
        return (
        <div>
        {
            fragrances.map((fragrance, index) => {
                <h2>{fragrance.Name}</h2>
                console.log(fragrance);
            })
        }
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning anything from your `map`

It should be

```
fragrances.map((fragrance, index) => { 
    return Boolean(fragrance.Name) && <h2 key={index}>{fragrance.Name}</h2>  
})
```

As mentioned in the comments you need to use a key when returning lists of components. Here i am using `index` but that is a bad practice (*read https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys*). Hopefully your `fragrance` objects have a unique `id` which is what you should use.

Comment: Thanks, works! btw, how can I check IF the name or category is empty or exists?

Comment: @NinoMerdzanovic `if (fragrance.Name) {/* Name exists and is not empty */}`

Comment: If you don't want to be that verbose you can use the following syntax (`fragrances.map((fragrance, i) => <h2 key={i}>{fragrance.Name}</h2> )`)

You should also set the key on every element.

Comment: This code will skip fragrances with null, undefined or empty names.
`fragrances.filter(fragrance => Boolean(fragrance.name)).map((fragrance, index) => <h2>{fragrance.Name}</h2>);`

Comment: @DmitryS. do you have a full version without minified?

Comment: @NinoMerdzanovic updated code and answer to include the discussion in the comments.

Comment: @NinoMerdzanovic. This version might be a bit more readable.
fragrances.filter((fragrance) => { return fragrance.name != null && fragrance.name !== ''; }).map((fragrance) => { return <h2>{fragrance.Name}</h2>; });